# How to "stamp" the same text on each page of a document

Tags: tools

I want to have drafting information appear on each page of document.

I have seen something similar in the Kluwer document class where it defines `\@oddfoot` and `\@evenfoot` for a lot of possibilities.

Is there an easier way than this? 
Is there a way to do it without overwriting existing headers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [the everypage module](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/everypage/) to execute Latex code just before each page is shipped.  You can use PS specials to put in things like watermarks in the page (cf. the watermark package in [the ncctools bundle](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/), which I belive uses this technique), or overlay graphics on the page using PS drawing packages.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I combine this with TikZ's ability to reference the current page for absolute positioning of the text (see TikZ 2.0 manual Section 15.13.2).

Answer (score 14):

There are a couple of packages to stamp a watermark on every page: `draftcopy` and `draftwatermark`.  Depending on the nature of what you want to stamp on every page, they may be useful to you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the package `fancyhdr` to simplify the creation and modification of page styles.

However, doing it manually isn’t that hard either. It basically boils down to redefining the `\ps@plain` command, so that this redefines `\@oddfoot` and `\@evenfoot`:

```
% Define a nice example stamp.
\newcommand\myoverlay{
  % Taken from the TikZ documentation.
  % NB: This requires \usepackage{tikz}!
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rotate=60,scale=10,text opacity=0.2]
      at (current page.center) {Example};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
}

% Save the old definition:
\let\old@ps@plain\ps@plain

\renewcommand\ps@plain{
  % First, load the old definition:
  \old@ps@plain

  % Now, save the previously (by \@old@ps@plain) defined footers:
  \let\old@oddfoot\@oddfoot
  \let\old@evenfoot\@evenfoot

  % Actual redefinition of the footer to include the overlay stamp.
  \gdef\@oddfoot{
    \old@oddfoot
    \myoverlay
  }
  \gdef\@evenfoot{
    \old@evenfoot
    \myoverlay
  }
}
```

Now tested, it works. But notice that it *only* works on pages whose page style is actually `plain`. Some pages – e.g. `\part` title pages – automatically define their page to have some other page style. This can of course be addressed by redefining those page styles as well. But I guess that using `fancyvrb` or the packages mentioned by Charles save a bit of work.

Answer (score 5):

ConTeXt provides layers for that purpose. You can read more about it at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers.

Comment: For using layers to get watermarks in ConTeXt, see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Draft_Watermark

Answer (score 4):

The 'background' package is another one that makes it simple to put a watermark (or other overlays) on pages.  Default setting, I believe, is to put a huge 'DRAFT' diagonally across the page:

http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=background